# GArray is not cleared on initialization as expected

Tags: c, arrays, glib

I was having some weird Glib behavior, searched the internet a little and found [this Glib tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/section6.html), the second code block to be specific:

```
//ex-garray-2.c
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h> // I added this to make it compile
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GArray* a = g_array_sized_new(TRUE, TRUE, sizeof(int), 16);
    printf("Array preallocation is hidden, so array size == %d\n", a->len);
    printf("Array was init'd to zeros, so 3rd item is = %d\n",
        g_array_index(a, int, 2));
    g_array_free(a, FALSE);

    // I removed some code here

    return 0;
}
```

So, the expected result should be

```
Array preallocation is hidden, so array size == 0
Array was init'd to zeros, so 3rd item is = 0
```

but I do get

```
Array preallocation is hidden, so array size == 0
Array was init'd to zeros, so 3rd item is = 901959560
```

I am running Gentoo Linux ~amd64 (64bit, testing) with gcc 4.5.3, glibc 2.13 and glib 2.26.1. I compiled the program using `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) -o ex-garray-2 ex-garray-2.c`

Any idea why I get the observed behavior and not the expected one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with GLib, but I found its documentation very misleading: the flag `clear_` in `g_array_sized_new` actually defines how `g_array_set_size` behaves, i.e., whether it sets the bits to zero or not **upon setting the size of the array**. Indeed, the [documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Arrays.html#GArray) of GLib says

> `g_array_sized_new` creates a new GArray with reserved_size elements preallocated and a reference count of 1. This avoids frequent reallocation, if you are going to add many elements to the array. **Note however that the size of the array is still 0.**

Therefore, you are trying to access an element whose index is larger than the size of the array. Try to set the size of the array using `g_array_set_size (a,16)` first, and then only you can access the 3rd item.

Answer (score -1):

The IBM documentation isn't correct. You have to dereference g_array_index() like this:

```
printf("%d\n", &g_array_index(array, type, index));
```

See http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-index